# Is postderef syntax on hashes supported?

Tags: perl, hash, postfix-notation

Let's say I have

```
my %foo;
```

Can I set keys `foo`, `bar`, `baz` to `a` `b` `c` by taking a slice and doing parallel assignment with postfix notation?

```
%foo->@{qw/foo bar baz/} = qw/a b c/
```

I used this syntax and I was told it was only "accidentally working". I don't see it generating a warning, and I also don't see it documented anywhere. Is this behavior supported or not?

Comment: Since deref syntax makes no sense on non-references, this would clearly seem to be a bug. This also breaks the expectation that `LEFT->@{RIGHT}` = `@{LEFT}{RIGHT}` – the circumfix deref would try to stringify `%foo` when substituted into that pattern. Please just use a normal `@foo{...}` slice.

Comment: `@foo{qw/foo bar baz/} = qw/a b c/;` or in case of reference `@{$fooref}{qw/foo bar baz/}=qw/a b c/`. Postfix syntax is new too me and I can not comment on it's usage.

Comment: The left side of `->` is supposed to be an expression that returns a reference.

Comment: An interesting bug! No way that that should work, and should be reported. (I also find it to work on my perlbrew v5.30, no warnings.)

Comment: It won't do it for an array, `Can't use an array as a reference...`

Comment: perlbug ref https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17722

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The left side of `->` is supposed to be an expression that returns a reference. Use anything else at your own risk.

---

`%foo->{a}` used to work.

```
$ 5.10t/bin/perl -e'my %foo; %foo->{a} = 1; print "ok\n";'
ok
```

This was deemed to be bug.

```
$ 5.12t/bin/perl -e'my %foo; %foo->{a} = 1; print "ok\n";'
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at -e line 1.
ok

$ 5.20t/bin/perl -e'my %foo; %foo->{a} = 1; print "ok\n";'
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at -e line 1.
ok

$ 5.22t/bin/perl -e'my %foo; %foo->{a} = 1; print "ok\n";'
Can't use a hash as a reference at -e line 1.
```

There's no reason to believe `%foo->@{...}` is any more valid than `%foo->{...}`.

---

Bug [reported](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17722).